# How can I make my function accept different types of input?

Tags: python

I want to create a function that takes in an input (can be in the form of an int, array or string) and returns whether its an narcissistic number or not.

So far I created a function that can take in an integer, and returns True if the narcissistic and False if not.

```
def is_narcissistic(num):

   total = []
   number = len(str(num)) #Find the length of the value
   power = int(number) #convert the length back to integer datatype
   digits = [int(x) for x in str(num)] #convert value to string and loop through, convert back to int and store in digits

   for i in digits:
     product = i**power # iterate through the number and take each i to the power of the length of int
     total.append(product) # append the result to the list total
     totalsum = sum(total)

   if totalsum == num:
     print (True)
   else:
     print(False)


print(is_narcissistic(153))
```

The problem however is that this should work for any kind of input like strings, or lists. For example:

> > input: (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9) ---  output: True, "All positive 1 digit integers are narcissistic"
> >
> > input: (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 22, 9) --- output: False, "At least 1 integer is not narcissistic"
> >
> > input: ("4")  --- output: True, "Numbers as strings are ok")
> >
> > input: ("words") --- output: False, "Strings that are not numbers are not ok")

So What should I add so that the function can take these inputs as well?

A Narcissistic number for example 153.
Because when you take each digit apart and take it to the power of the length of the digit (3 in this case) you get the number itself.

1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3 = 153

Comment: Doesn't your code already handle some of these cases?

Comment: Since the actual question is completely unrelated to narcissistic numbers, it would've been better to completely omit that from the question and focus on the important part: _"How can I make my function accept different types of input?"_

Comment: @RoryDaulton Done, thanks for the feedback

Comment: @Aran-Fey Done, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is check these special cases:

```
def is_narcissistic(num):
    if isinstance(num, str): # is is a string?
        if num.isdigit(): # does is consist purely out of numbers?
            num = int(num)
        else:
            return False
    if isinstance(num, (tuple,list)):
        return all(is_narcissistic(v) for v in num)
    # the rest of your code
```

Also you have to change the end of your function. You should not print, but return to use the value later:

```
if totalsum == num:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

If you want to be able to call it without the extract parenthesis for tuple, you can use this:

```
def is_narcissistic(*args):
    if len(args) == 1:
        num = args[0]
    else:
        num = args
    # The code from above
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
print(is_narcissistic(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)) # True
print(is_narcissistic(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 22, 9)) # False
print(is_narcissistic(0, 1, "2", 3, "4", 5, 6, 7, "22", 9)) #False
```

The complete code is here:

```
def is_narcissistic(*args):
    if len(args) == 1:
        num = args[0]
    else:
        num = args
    if isinstance(num, str):
        if num.isdigit():
            num = int(num)
        else:
            return False
    if isinstance(num, (tuple, list)):
        return all(is_narcissistic(v) for v in num)
    total = []
    number = len(str(num))  # Find the length of the value
    power = int(number)  # convert the length back to integer datatype
    digits = [int(x) for x in str(num)]  # convert value to string and loop through, convert back to int and store in digits

    for i in digits:
        product = i ** power  # iterate through the number and take each i to the power of the length of int
        total.append(product)  # append the result to the list total
        totalsum = sum(total)

    if totalsum == num:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Thank you @Megalng ! I usually do print to check if my code is working. Although I understand what your code is checking, I still get this error when I run it: "TypeError: is_narcissistic() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given" - should I use try/ except?

Comment: @Daphne How are you calling the function? You have to call it like this: `is_narcissistic((0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))` with to parenthesis to create a `tuple`.

Comment: @Daphne I added other possibility to call it without extra parenthesis

Comment: @Megalng I see , should I use that part on top of all the other code?

Comment: @Daphne That was the plan. Consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: @ Ok I am a bit confused, I tried to implement the code in different ways  but get an error anyways. Could you maybe put the whole code for the last implementation in your answer. :)

Comment: @Daphne Ok Done.

Comment: @Megalng I get it!! :D